# Add numbers with the word "add"

Tags: java, addition, scriptengine

I am writing to offer an application in Java right now and instead of using the operator "+", the user of the application can literally use the word "add" to add two numbers together.

I'm quite stuck on how to do this because I can't really use a method in order to complete the function considering I'd have to type "add()" rather than just "add". Unless there is a way to execute a method without the parentheses. Would I have to write a completely new class or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Why on earth would you *want* to do this?

Comment: I literally just want to try something different, I like making myself think.

Comment: @Twisterz The closest you can get to this behavior in Java is to write your own method which would take two arguments and an operator and compute the result. I wouldn't suggest this because it will quickly become cumbersome, inefficient and confusing.

Comment: @Twisterz Not in Java, but take a look at Scala if you would like to define your own alphanumeric infix operators.  Whether it is possible do this on existing classes such as `Int` is a good question to investigate while making yourself think.

Comment: in coding there is no really a reason (aside from the fact that you cant do this) to do this, however you can do this on the user interface Like if the user enters two numbers and the word "add" 1 add 2, then you you can search the string for the word add and if its there you call the add(x,y) function... something like that

Comment: @RayToal This is a good point I hadn't though of that I will have to look into

Comment: @user710502 That is actually not a bad idea

Comment: @user710502  I'd put all the logic into a `ScriptEngine`.  See my answer.

Comment: @Jeffrey This seems to be coming round to 'offer the ability to the end user'.  It makes a lot more sense that way.

Comment: Jeez there's a lot of good answers i honestly don't know which to choose...

Comment: Choose whichever you think is the best.  But it might be best to leave it for at least a day.  After all.  There might be more answers just around the corner.  Let us know how you go.  :)

Comment: BTW - I made a **Significant edit based on comments.** to the question, please review my changes and roll back if incorrect.  If correct, you might edit out the *italics*. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(An expansion on the idea presented by user710502)

You can use [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).

```
double a = Double.parseDouble(some user input);
double b = Double.parseDouble(some user input);
String operation = some user input; // i.e. "add", "subtract"
Method operator = Calculations.class.getMethod(operation, double.class, double.class);
// NoSuchMethodException is thrown if method of operation name isn't found
double result = (Double) operator.invoke(null, a, b);
```

In some sort of calculations class:

```
public static double add(double a, double b) {
    return a + b;
}

public static double subtract(double a, double b) {
    return a - b;
}

// and so forth
```

Comment: For further reading on reflection, http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

Answer (score 3):

Just a little explanation on what you could do based on what the user enters:

```
int x = get it from the user;
int y = get it from the user;
string operation = get it from the user;
```

- Create separate methods for the operations `(i.e  add(int x, int y), multiply(int x, int y), etc..)`

Then create a method thag gets the values (x, y, string) say.. you can call it `calculate(int x, int y, string operation)`

Then in the calculuate method have a switch statement:

```
switch(operation)
{
case "add":
      add(x,y);
      break;
case "multiply":
      multiply(x,y);
      break;
etc...
}
```

Well, got you something to think about :).

Comment: This can be even further simplified by using reflection.  Instead of having a case for each method of the same name, the method could be invoked with x and y as the parameters.  I wrote this concept as an answer earlier (still have it existing in answer box if anyone is interested), but didn't post it because I reread the question and decided it wasn't a good answer.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing it @Vulcan

Comment: @ Vulcan yeah man, put it out.. i was just giving an intro idea of what could be done.. and by no means thought to optimize it.. but if you are that guy.. it would be cool :)

Comment: @user710502 It might not be an optimization as far as speed (reflection takes more time to execute than a switch statement, if I recall correctly, but the difference is marginal).  However, it simplifies the code and eases implementing new operators.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this in Java. You have two options:

1)Use a preprocessor. 
2)Write it in a different language. You can write things in other languages and still have it compatible with Java classes and libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The consensus in comments seems to be 'Why would you want to do this?  It is slow and cumbersome'.  While the latter part is true, it is commonly done.  See [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) as an example.  Here is a demo of the [JavaScript ScriptEngine](http://www.pscode.org/jse.html) in an applet.

The reader might note that `ScriptEngine` is an interface, suggesting an answer of 'implement your own script engine, based on the rules required'.  Whether or not it is a good idea to create another scripting language, is left as an exercise for the reader.