# How to turn a string into an operator in Java?

Tags: java, string, calculator

I'm trying to make a simple text based calculator in java *my first program, EVER* and I can't figure out how to turn an input `String` into a variable `opOne`. I would then attempt to operate `numOne` against `numTwo` using `opOne` as the operator. 
Code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

public class ReadString {

   public static void main (String[] args) {


      System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");


      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
      int numOne = 0 ;
      int numTwo = 0 ;
      String opOne = null;

      while(true){
      try {
          numOne = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
          break;
      } catch (IOException error) {
         System.out.println("error; try again.");
         System.exit(1);
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
          System.out.println("error;try again.");

      }

      }

      System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");

      while(true){
      try {

          numTwo = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
          break;
       } catch (IOException error2) {
          System.out.println("error");
          System.exit(1);
       } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
          System.out.println("error;try again.");

       }
      }

      System.out.println("What would you like to do with " + numOne + " and " + numTwo + "?");

      try {
          operator = br.readLine();
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
          System.out.println("error");
          System.exit(1);
       } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
          System.out.println("error");

       } 
   }
}
```

Comment: *"text based calculator"*  Use [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) instead.  E.G. 1) [in web page (applet)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12023586/418556) 2) [non GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8162055/418556)  3) [simple GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6426684/418556) 4) [nice GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556)..

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way of doing this would be a sequence of `if-then-else` statements:

```
if ("+".equals(opOne)) {
    res = numOne + numTwo;
} else if ("-".equals(opOne)) {
    res = numOne - numTwo;
} ...
```

An advanced way would be to define an interface for your operators, and putting the instances in a `Map` container:

```
interface Operation {
    int calculate(int a, int b);
}

static final Map<String,Operation> opByName = new HashMap<String,Operation>();
static {
    opByName.put("+", new Operation() {
        public int calculate(int a, int b) {
            return a+b;
        }
    });
    opByName.put("-", new Operation() {
        public int calculate(int a, int b) {
            return a-b;
        }
    });
    opByName.put("*", new Operation() {
        public int calculate(int a, int b) {
            return a*b;
        }
    });
    opByName.put("/", new Operation() {
        public int calculate(int a, int b) {
            return a/b;
        }
    });
}
```

With a map initialized like this, you can perform calculations as follows:

```
int res = opByName.get(opOne).calculate(numOne, numTwo);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way you can convert a Java string to an operator. It's not a Java data type.

```
   double Calculate(String opOne, double numOne, double numTwo) {  
      if (opOne.equals("+"))  
        return numOne + numTwo;  
      else if (opOne.equals("-"))  
        return numOne - numTwo;  
      else if (opOne.equals("*"))  
        return numOne * numTwo; 
      else if (opOne.equals("/"))  
        return numOne / numTwo;   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Computer, by itself, does not know what an `operator` (in human language) is, so you need to tell the computer to do that.

```
String opOne;

try {
    opOne = br.readLine();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("error");
    System.exit(1);
}

switch (opOne) {  //Note: String in switch is possible only from Java 7, check your version
     "+": System.out.println('Result: ' + (numOne + numTwo)); break; 
     "-": System.out.println('Result: ' + (numOne - numTwo)); break;
     // and so on...
}
```

Comment: I can't vote you up, since I am new, but I will say that a great big "THANK YOU"

Comment: I don't see any runtime teaching